# How to add a share button in Django to share a post

Tags: python, django

I am relatively new to Django, I have a blog that I have been working on. However, I am having problem implementing a sharing button to share my posts on social media, with the title and thumbnail,specifically Facebook and WhatsApp.I have researched and googled all the possible solutions, but neither of them tends to solve my problem. Not many tutorials out here have covered this issue. I have used the social_share,django_addthis, and social_share_widgets but none of them seem to help.

Here are my models and templates

```
class Post(models.Model):
        author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,blank=True,unique=True)
        thumbnail = models.ImageField()        

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('details', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}
{% load social_share %}
{% load blog_tags %}


{% block content %}
    <p>{{post.content| safe}}</p>

    <div class="social-contact">
        <a href="#" id="shown" style="background-color: red;"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Share</a>    

        <a  id="hidden" href="https://facebook.com/share?url=http://devbrian.com{{ request.get_full_path|urlencode }}" class="facebook-link"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>
        <a  id="hidden" href="https://www.twitter.com/share?url=http://devbrian.com{{ request.get_full_path|urlencode }}" class="twitter-link"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
        <a  id="hidden" href="https://www.instagram.com/share?url=http://devbrian.com{{ request.get_full_path|urlencode }}" class="instagram-link"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i> Instagram</a>

        <a style="background-color: green;" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?+254799043853=+*YOURNUMBER*&text=%20*{{ request.get_full_path|urlencode }}&title=<your title>&summary=<your desc>&source=http://devbrian.com*" class="youtube-link"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i> Whatsapp</a>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I will appreciate your help

Comment: What's the issue with your current solution?

Comment: So far I have encountered three types of issues, The first was Parameter 'href' should represent a valid URL in Facebook
The second is "Sorry, something went wrong.
We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.",The third is that the post can be shared on twitter button the thumbnail and title doest appear

Answer (score 0):

Maybe yo can use this, i find online it's not mine, but works for me.

[http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://{{](http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://%7B%7B) request.get_full_path|urlencode }}

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32013139)